# I need to run specific code for 3 times only in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sliding

I need to animate a sliding with jquery. but only for 3 times. I wrote this code. But this more than 3 times. Please help me to fix or give different codes. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var i=0;
    while (i<3) {                    
        $('a.nextbtn').click (function () {
            $('ul.post-cat-sliding').stop().animate({"left": "-=596"},1500);
        });
        i++;
    }
});
```

and also i have previous button.. so if i click previous button slide should go back.

Comment: What do you mean `only 3 times`? You are binding an animation to a click event, do you only want to let the user click the link 3 times? BTW your current code will run the same code three times whenever you click on a `a.nextbtn` element.

Comment: I assume you have a slideshow with 4 items (so clicking on "next" should work only 3 times). I would take a different approach completely: don't count the number of allowed clicks, but on each click check whether you're at the last slide in which case do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current code you are actually attaching 3 click-events with a single button rather than limiting it to three clicks. So with current code I think your slider will be passing 3 slides with one click.

Try the code down-below:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
   var i=0;
   $('a.nextbtn').click (function () {
      if(i < 3) {
         $('ul.post-cat-sliding').stop().animate({"left": "-=596"},1500);
         i++;
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` might seems a little too verbose.

Maybe you might like some of these approaches:

```
for(i in [1,2,3]){
    console.log('three times')
}
```

or

```
for(i in new Array(3).fill()){
    console.log('three times')
}
```

or

```
for(i in '...'.split('')){
    console.log('three times')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a for loop instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.nextbtn').click (function(){
        for(var i = 0; i<3;i++)
        {
            $('ul.post-cat-sliding').stop().animate({"left": "-=596"},1500);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Was only conserned with the looping when I read the post. If you want the animation to run 3 times when the nextbtn is clicked you should use the above code. You can reuse the code with `a.prevbtn`